# QTP- How to connect to a 32 bit DSN from a 64 bit environment (Windows 7 - 64 bit)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, qtp, dsn

How to connect to a 32 bit SQL server using DSN from a 64 bit environment (Windows 7 - 64 bit) through QTP.

I tried by creating DSN from this C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe but that gives error: "Error # -2147467259 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". Please help me how can i get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect a  32 bits DSN to 64 bits Window enviornment as the data source name is not compatible with  it